# Algorithm to calculate rref in GF(2)?

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra, galois-field

I have a `matrix :: [[Int]]` whose elements are all either zero or one.

How can I efficiently implement `rref` in [GF(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29)?

<sub>If LU decomposition can be used to calculate **rref(matrix)** in GF(2), any example or elaboration on the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.</sub>

Comment: You basically want an [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), and that [is available](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/latest/doc/html/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Algorithms.html#g:10).

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't think it's possible to make an efficient GF(2) implementation using hmatrix, it was designed to handle "big" numbers, not bits.
2. You definitely don't want to use a `Double` to encode a Bit, that's 64 times more memory than what you actually need.
3. Have you searched for `rref` algorithms that are optimized for GF(2) ? A generic Gaussian elimination or LU decomposition might not be the best solution in GF(2).

Comment: A quick web search for "efficient GF(2) matrices" seems to return some potentially interesting results.